# Implementing GEo XACML using wso2 identity server

Tags: wso2, authorization, access-control, xacml, abac

I want to create a simple GeoXACML policy which would grant access to files only when the user is present inside a polygon (coordinates) using WSO2 Identity Server. But I cannot find the location-based access control option on the panel. How can I implement that?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

GeoXACML is an optional profile of the XACML standard. I'm not sure WSO2 implements it. Have a look at the [GeoXACML Implementation website](https://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/geoxacml) to figure out where you can get your hands on it.